# "Qt Embedded" fonts in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, fonts, qt-creator

When selecting a font for a widget in Qt Creator 4.6.2, some of the fonts have a postfix `[Qt embedded]` in their name. E.g. `DejaVu Sans Mono [Qt Embedded]`.

This is a snapshot from the Qt Creator property editor:

[image]

What does `[Qt Embedded]` mean exactly?

Comment: You could show an image of what you get, I do not see that happening in my case.  :(

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you see the same in your Creator instance?